# What is the formal name of the set of 'orthogonal pair of axes'?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, terminology, non-convex-optimization, monotone-operator-theory

If $X$ is any (finite or infinite dimensional) Hilbert space, define the set
$$C := \{(x,y)\in X \times X~|~ \langle x,y \rangle = 0\}.$$

What is this set called in literature? Any ''formal name'' reference would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't also want $\langle x,x\rangle=\langle y,y\rangle=1$?

Comment: No, one can have $x=y$, i.e., $\langle x,x \rangle =\langle y,y \rangle = 0  \Rightarrow  (0,0) \in C$.